# Unauthenticated Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, passport

Estoy trabajando en un *Login* con *Laravel Passport* para después consumir esta *API* en *Angular* y estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

Cuando tiro un GET en Postman a la siguiente ruta `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tramites` con los headers `Accept: application/json` y mi token `Authorization: Bearer xxxx` me devuelve lo siguiente:

> "message": "Unauthenticated."

No entiendo porque sucede esto ya que le estoy pasando el token del usuario generado, tendría que acceder.

Mi api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
Route::ApiResource('tramites', 'TramiteController');});
```

Mi Controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $persona = Persona::whereUsuario($request->Usuario)->first();
        if(!is_null($persona) && ($request->Contrasena == $persona->Contrasena))
        {
            
            $persona->App_Id = Str::random(100);
            $persona->save();

            return response()->json([
                'res' => true,
                'token' => $persona->App_Id,
                'message' => 'Login succesfully'
            ], 200);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'res' => false,
                'message' => 'Login wrong'
            ], 400);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Muestra cómo generas el token

Comment: @L.Flor Edite el post y agregue la parte donde genero el token

Comment: Según la documentación de Laravel el token debes guardarlo en `api_token` en tu caso usas `App_ID`

Comment: @nax Si Nax lo que pasa que no tengo forma de cambiar esto en mi BD, ya que es una BD que ya esta construida

Comment: Y entonces cómo esperas que el token funcione? el código de `auth:api` espera que el token esté en esa field pero tu lo guardas en otra.

Dicho eso puedes hacer un ALTER TABLE y añadir la nueva columna... No estoy seguro si laravel tiene una forma de configurar ese middleware para que lea de otra columna